# Limit for concurrent connections to the same host in Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, concurrency

Why is the code (or any similar)

```
var http = require('http');
var async = require('async');

async.forever(function(next) {
    http.get('http://google.com', function(res) {
        next();
    });
});
```

executing only 5 times with the latest released Node (0.10.28)?

Answer (score 2):

By default, Node sends HTTP requests with `Connection: Keep-Alive` header set, so the connection is not closed after one request. And by default the maximum number of concurrent connections to the same server:port is set to 5. This is controlled by `http.globalAgent.maxSockets` property.

It's actually mentioned in the documentation but it's hard to find if you don't know where to look or don't just read through all docs. Also, these classes are being rewritten now and next releases will have different behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the behaviour has changed (in node7 possibly before) and the default is now an unlimitted amount of connections https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v7.x/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets